# How to get value inside some div below a "::before" using the full Xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would like to retrieve a data inside several `<div>` and those are between a `::before` and `::after`.

I'm using the full xpath because I'm retrieving this data from google sheet using the `IMPORTXML` function

Here are the two xpaths I've used, neither of which works
(Using both in the google chrome console, they do point me to the right element)

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img//@data-src
```

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[@class='table-wide']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img//@data-src
```

[EDIT] And to check the HTML code, you can go on this page : https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Light_Cone/List and inspect the first image of the table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="client-js windows desktop dyiffygjh idc0_347 ve-available portrait" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-0 ns-subject page-Light_Cone_List rootpage-Light_Cone skin-fandomdesktop action-view ooui-theme-fandomooui wiki-houkaistarrail theme-fandomdesktop-dark no-featured-video wikia-bar-visible menu-bright page-dark">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div id="age-gate"></div>
    <div class="resizable-container">
      <div class="page has-right-rail">
        <main class="page__main" lang="en">
          <div id="content" class="page-content ve-init-mw-desktopArticleTarget-targetContainer">
            <div id="mw-content-text" class="mw-body-content mw-content-ltr" lang="en" dir="ltr">
              <div class="mw-parser-output">
                <div class="table-wide">
                  ::before
                  <div class="table-wide-inner">
                    <table class="article-table sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="width: content-min">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Icon & Name</th>
                          <th class="mw-collapsible headerSort mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablerarity" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Rarity</th>
                          <th class="mw-collapsible headerSort mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablepath" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Path</th>
                          <th class="mw-collapsible headerSort mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablestats" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Stats</th>
                          <th class="mw-collapsible headerSort mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetable" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Passive</th>
                          <th class="mw-collapsible headerSort mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablecharacters" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Featured Characters</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <a href="/wiki/A_Secret_Vow" title="A Secret Vow"><img alt="Light Cone A Secret Vow" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/houkai-star-rail/images/a/a2/Light_Cone_A_Secret_Vow.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20230719025735" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="50" height="59" data-image-name="Light Cone A Secret Vow.png" data-image-key="Light_Cone_A_Secret_Vow.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/houkai-star-rail/images/a/a2/Light_Cone_A_Secret_Vow.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20230719025735" class="ls-is-cached lazyloaded"></a><br>
                            <a href="/wiki/A_Secret_Vow" title="A Secret Vow">A Secret Vow</a>
                          </td>
                          <td class="mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablepath"><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/The_Destruction" title="The Destruction"><img alt="Path The Destruction" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/houkai-star-rail/images/3/37/Path_The_Destruction.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/20?cb=20230508230545" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="20" height="20" data-image-name="Path The Destruction.png" data-image-key="Path_The_Destruction.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/houkai-star-rail/images/3/37/Path_The_Destruction.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/20?cb=20230508230545" class="ls-is-cached lazyloaded"></a> <a href="/wiki/The_Destruction" title="The Destruction">The Destruction</a></span></td>
                          <td class="mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablestats"><b>HP:</b>&nbsp;48~1,058<br>
                          <b>ATK:</b>&nbsp;21~476<br>
                          <b>DEF:</b>&nbsp;12~264</td>
                          <td class="mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetable"><b>Spare No Effort</b><br>
                          Increases DMG dealt by the wearer by <b>20</b>~<b>40</b>%. The wearer also deals an extra <b>20</b>~<b>40</b>% of DMG to enemies with a higher HP percentage than the wearer.</td>
                          <td class="mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible" id="mw-customcollapsible-lightconetablecharacters">
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="/wiki/Arlan" title="Arlan">Arlan</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              ::after
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate all the support ! Thanks !

Comment: Please provide actual HTML code, not a picture of text. Read about why to avoid this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thanks Chris, i added the URL to have all the details, but also upload a piece of the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the following value from the URL of `https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Light_Cone/List` using `IMPORTXML`.

  ```
  https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/houkai-star-rail/images/a/a2/Light_Cone_A_Secret_Vow.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20230719025735
  ```

In this case, how about the following XPath?

```
//tr[2]/td[1]//@data-src
```

And, how about the following sample formula?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[2]/td[1]//@data-src")
```

- In this case, `https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Light_Cone/List` is put into cell "A1".

When this sample formula is used, the following result is obtained. In this test, the cell "A3" has a formula of `=IMAGE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[2]/td[1]//@data-src"))`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike !
It works perfecly ! I just change the `//tr[2]` into `//tr` to get an images list.
And to add more details on the image, i use `REGEXREPLACE` function to remove all chars after the .png in the image link i got :
`REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(.*)/revision.*","$1")`